Cannot break .each() even though if condition true in cypress
Below is my it block code which has each loop and it does not breaking even though I passed return false when the if condition true and continue executing the loop.
cy.get('@gemTitle').then((gemTitle) => {
            editor.getGEMs().each(($gem) => {
                cy.wrap($gem).dblclick()
                cy.get('[formcontrolname="symbolName"]').should('be.visible').invoke('val').then(($gemName) => {
                    if ($gemName.includes(gemTitle)) {
                        cy.log('Comparing gemName: ' + $gemName + ' with gemTitle: ' + gemTitle)
                        cy.get('[data-cy="cancelGemFeeding"]').click()
                        return false
                    } else {
                        cy.get('[data-cy="cancelGemFeeding"]').click()
                    }
                })
            })
            cy.wait(1000)
            cy.get("[class*='resize-handle-top']").should('exist').parent().parent().dblclick()
            cy.get('[data-cy="cancelGemFeeding"]').click()
        })


The docs say You can stop the .each() loop early by returning false in the callback function but you are returning inside the then callback instead. Move the return to the each callback, and reconstruct the logic to make it work.
